# Restart chrome browser on Ubuntu 16.04 when starting up Docker container running React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, docker, ubuntu

I am working to deploy a docker container that runs a react app that performs a `fetch` request to another docker container running a node server. Docker is deployed on Ubuntu 16.04 but when I build the container and deploy, the chrome browser will continue to display the old UI until a hard refresh or browser restart is performed.

Is there a way for me to clear the browser cache, hard refresh or restart the browser when the react app starts? I am building the react app with `create-react-app`.

For reference, I am deploying this app on many machines so doing anything manual on the host machine is not ideal.

Comment: I don't think this question is especially Docker-specific.  [This question](/questions/34388614/how-to-force-update-single-page-application-spa-pages) seems relevant; [this one](/questions/46364221/how-to-do-force-reload-for-the-first-time-after-the-web-app-is-deployed) suggests configuring Webpack to produce a unique filename per build which gets around some of the pain.

Answer (score 0):

Docker caches the results of your first build to make it faster for subsequent builds. You could try this command to clear the cache when you deploy.

```
docker build --no-cache -t u12_core -f u12_core .
```

However I think your problem is with the browser cache on chrome.

You could disable cache when DevTools is open. (This option can be found inside Settings -> General)

Alternatively, you could use one of the [chrome cache cleaner extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/classic-cache-killer/kkmknnnjliniefekpicbaaobdnjjikfp/related).